# Android Navigation Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example--- is unknown to this NavController

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am getting an Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, the error occurs only when i navigate to `RegisterFragment` from `LoginFragment` and then press back button to go to previous fragment(`LoginFragment`) and enter email and password and press login button. When i comment the line `view!!.findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeContainerFragment())`, the error doesn't occur, but i have to navigate to `HomeFragment`. How to fix it?

**Note:** The Error doesn't occur when you don't navigate to `RegisterFragment`

LoginFragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
{
    val binding: FragmentLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)

    val login = binding.loginBtn
    val emailField = binding.inputEmail
    val passwordField = binding.inputPassword
    val signUp = binding.loginSignup

    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    signUp.setOnClickListener {
        view!!.findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToRegisterFragment())
    }

    login.setOnClickListener {
        val email = emailField.text.toString().trim()
        val password = passwordField.text.toString().trim()

        if(email.isEmpty())
        {
            .................
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
        {
            .................
        }

        viewModel.userLogin(email,password)
    }

    viewModel.loginAuthData.observe(this, Observer { userAuthData ->
        if(userAuthData.checkAuth != null)
        {
            if(userAuthData.checkAuth!!)
            {
                Snackbar.make(activity!!.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Auth Pass", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //The error doesn't occur if i comment this line >>
                view!!.findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeContainerFragment())
            }
            else
            {
                Snackbar.make(activity!!.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Auth Fail", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })

    return binding.root
}
```

Error:

```
  Process: com.example.---, PID: 24721
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.---:id/action_loginFragment_to_homeContainerFragment is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:789)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:907)
    at com.example.---.ui.login.LoginFragment$onCreateView$3.onChanged(LoginFragment.kt:71)
    at com.example.---.ui.login.LoginFragment$onCreateView$3.onChanged(LoginFragment.kt:20)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
    at com.example.---.viewModel.LoginViewModel.authCallBack(LoginViewModel.kt:37)
    at com.example.---.viewModel.LoginViewModel.access$authCallBack(LoginViewModel.kt:12)
    at com.example.---.viewModel.LoginViewModel$firebaseUserAuth$1.invoke(LoginViewModel.kt:15)
    at com.example.---.viewModel.LoginViewModel$firebaseUserAuth$1.invoke(LoginViewModel.kt:12)
    at com.example.---.data.FirebaseUserAuth$login$1.onComplete(FirebaseUserAuth.kt:27)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `viewModel.loginAuthData.observe(this, Observer {})` in `onCreateView()`, i.e., using the `Fragment` (via `this`) as the LifecycleOwner for your observing. This is always wrong - you should instead use `viewLifecycleOwner` when observing from `onCreateView()`:

```
viewModel.loginAuthData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
   ...
})
```

How LiveData works is that it continues to stay registered until the given `LifecycleOwner` is destroyed. When you pass `this`, it waits for the Fragment itself to be destroyed. However, Fragments are **not** destroyed while on the back stack (only their view and hence their `viewLifecycleOwner` is destroyed). This means that the *original* LiveData never unregisters its Observer.

This means that when `onCreateView()` happens a second time (i.e., you hit the back button and the view is recreated), a *second* Observer is created and registered. You now have **two** Observers running simultaneously. As they both run, the first one successfully runs and calls `navigate()`. When the second one runs, the NavController has already moved to the next destination, so any actions registered on the previous destination are no longer found, giving you an `IllegalArgumentException`.

By using `viewLifecycleOwner`, the original LiveData is correctly destroyed when the Fragment's view is destroyed. This means when you hit back and `onCreateView` is called again, only one Observer is active at a time and you won't run into this issue.

Comment: And what about `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` should i also change it to `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner`

Comment: Yep, anything tied to the view should use `viewLifecycleOwner`

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the NavController of the containing `Activity` `Activity.findNavController(IdOfView)` instead of `view!!.findNavController()`

For more on Navigation: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/package-summary#findnavcontroller

Comment: what should be passed in `activity!!.findNavController(????)` parameter?

Comment: The resource id of the view

Comment: `activity!!.findNavController(R.id.loginFragment)` not working